# Device to record cell phone calls from an Android smartphone

Tags: wireless, smartphones, microphones, audio-recording, telephony

Ideally, all cell phones would have integrated functionality to record calls.  After all, they directly handle all the audio of the calls, and have plenty of storage to save them.  Plus, the phone knows the Caller ID and contact information, and so can easily add meta data.  Finally, the phone knows exactly when the call began and ended, and can add that meta data as well.

Unfortunately, many smartphones have no integrated functionality to record calls.  And when they do, often the manufacturer disables it at the factory (I'm looking at you, Samsung).

There are many Android apps available to record calls, but most of them have severe limitations, especially with recent versions of Android (Google has reportedly made it even harder to record our own phone calls.)

I'm seeking recommendations for hardware to record cell phone conversations.  Ideally, it won't require the use of a headset, but I'm not 100% opposed to that option.  Also, I would really prefer it to not require any wires.

The only product I've found so far is the [Waytronic WT-RS1 mobile phone call recording headset](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001922874826.html). It, however, has several significant flaws:

1. It requires the use of the headset, so if you have an incoming call, and you don't have your headset with you, you're out of luck.
2. Their most "deluxe" version has only a paltry 512MB of storage (that's MB, not GB!).
3. I haven't been able to find any information that indicates that it stores any useful metadata, such as the phone number, contact name, or timestamp of the call.

Ideally, I would like a small Bluetooth or WiFi device with a microSD card that can fit in my pocket to record all calls and their metadata.

*Note: Call recording is legal in my jurisdiction.*

Comment: Are you saying [software solutions](https://search.f-droid.org/?q=call+record&lang=en) don't work?

Comment: @ChrisWesseling I have yet to find a software solution that works reliably.  And on newer versions of Android, Google has made it very difficult to write an effective call recording app.